# Should I mention my PhD in a PhD scholarship application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, funding, program-committee

I did not like my Msc. specialization (one of Chemistry streams). I won a PhD scholarship overseas. Though the area (protein engineering) was my favorite area, I graduated without having enough knowledge and skills due to the following reasons:

- the supervisor did not allow me to work on my chosen advanced topic and made me work on a title that is unfit for a PhD level,
- met with an accident, my recovery took my research time, and
- unbearable racism challenge in the lab.

**Since I am more interested in the field** I want to learn it by applying again for a PhD scholarship abroad, it could be in a different department: Chemistry, Bioengineering, Biotechnology, Biomedical Engineering,.. research that encompasses protein engineering.

If I disclose my PhD, what I think of as **advantages** are:

- to let the selection committee know I have not **ONLY** been offering courses since 2011,
- I am not applying from scratch, I have some background about it.
- to let them know I had won acscholarship abroad, if they may consider it as great achievement.

**Disadvantages**

- they may think I distanced myself from research for a long period of time (from 2011-to date). UNDERSTAND IT FROM MY CV, EDUCATION HISTORY
- they may select only the one who has background about it in their M.Sc.
- they may give the chance to the one who have no PhD

**If I state my publication and conferences in my CV to let them know my background by CONCEALING my PhD, a series of questions may pop up in the selection committee’s mind**:

- how were you able to do research on protein engineering while your Msc. field is Inorganic,
- how was it possible to work on it with someone in even abroad?
- in the publication it is stated that your affiliation is X University which belongs to other country (not the one mentioned you have been working in), were you student there, or did you go for visiting, for internship, ….

if you believe that there is still something to say to convince them while disclosing my PhD, please make a suggestion.

Comment: It depends on specifics but it may well be that you'd be obliged to mention your previous PhD. For sure it can be expected to be part of your standard CV, so it may be seen as deception if you don't (assuming anyone finds out). It may also be that depending on what your CV says about the time in question, it raises more questions if you don't state you got a PhD from that time than if you do.

Comment: You already finished a PhD? Or did you leave the program withouth a PhD title? If the first one is the case, I doubt that many places will give a sholarship to a person that already holds a PhD.

Comment: what if I apply to different department?

Answer (score 3):

In Germany, you have to list all previous studies when applying to a university (no matter if is for a BA, MA or PHD). Failure to list all previous academic history can lead to expulsion from the program (and in case of receiving a scholarship, you might be required to return the money), and you could even be sued. I imagine the situation is similar in other countries. Not disclosing a PhD is thus a very bad idea. I think already having a PhD might limit your chances to get a scholarship PhD position, as those a rare are rather given to people that do not already hold a PhD. Nevertheless, you should disclose it.

Comment: The same would be true in US.

Comment: what if I apply to different department?

Comment: I heard it would be useful if I apply to **different department** in US

Comment: Government and fellowships offers scholarship funding to produce highly skilled professionals. You got the funding and opportunities, but what did they get out of your first program? Trying to double dip here would be outright fraud (hint: if you have to ask "should I lie?", you are very likely deeply in the wrong already). Sorry, life is hard sometimes and we face many obstacles, but your description does not paint an experience so extreme to be likely to elicit sympathy. Concealing your first PhD will get you in a big big trouble; time to work with what you have.

Comment: I believe this is actually not true for becoming a doctoral candidate (or getting the actual doctorate) in Germany, because that is (usually, although state authorities are trying *hard* to change it) purely a matter between the respective committee of the "Fakultät" and you. You're not a student per se (you *can* inscribe as "Promotionsstudent", pay your fee, and get cheap enty into museums etc.).

Comment: Thank you all for your ideas. how ever I don think you did read the whole description, thereby did not got me what I mean by just the question.                                        
                                                                                                                                           
 due to some reasons I graduated PhD with a knowledge and skills that qualifies me neither for post doc nor for job   application. I want to extend it by applying PhD again but to different department that encompasses researches related to the area that I did in my PhD. ...

Comment: ....(continued from the previous). If I conceal my PhD and just mention my conferences and publication in order to show the admission committee that I have some backgrounds about the area, they will notice on the article that I was affiliated with X department in Y university which is different from my working place- causes questions in their mind. if I do not mention it, they may not accept me over lack of background. What should I do? should I disclose it along with the reasons that caused me to have little knowledge and skills to convince them that I need another PhD?...

Comment: NB: My idea is under the condition of “If there is an option to do not disclose my PhD in the application”

Answer (score 2):

You have not mentioned the most serious consequence - expulsion. For most universities in developed countries, you have the obligation to provide information about all of your tertiary education activities including PhD. Failure to do this will result in punishments once it is disclosed.

Also, many universities will not offer any scholarship/stipend to students who already earned a PhD degree. Check the conditions for research scholarship for more details.

Comment: what if I apply to different department?

Comment: @Yasin From the same university? You will not have to disclose anything because they already have your information in the database. You may get accepted to some programs, owever, for research scholarship, you still have to check the conditions because for many universities I know, it is clearly state that there is no scholarship for those who already earned a PhD degree.

Comment: no. not even in the same country. what if I brief the **admission committee** my **reasons** **(LISTED IN THE POST)** to apply for PhD again? may it be useful?